# Wp7 Mango Clipboard access / upgrade project from 7.0 to 7.1

Tags: clipboard, windows-phone-7

The docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043%28v=VS.96%29.aspx state the System.Windows.Clipboard should be available in Windows Phone 7.1. I tried using it in the Visual Studio Express 2010 (beta 2 for Mango from June) but when

using System.Windows.Clipboard;

VS complains :

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Clipboard' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Do I miss anything or is this just not ready yet?

**UPDATE:**
Seems to work if I start a new project targetting Windows Phone 7.1 from the beginning. I just don't know how to change the setting from 7.0 to 7.1...

Thanks a lot!
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Clipboard` is a class and not a namespace. Therefore, you cannot declare it in the class header like you're doing it. Simply add a `using System.Windows;` and use `Clipboard.<method>` inside the application.

As it was stated in the comments, the problem lies in the fact that a project build for NoDo is used with Mango dev tools. The project was not automatically updated and still relies on WP OS 7.0. To upgrade it, right click on the project in Solution Explorer and click on **Upgrade to Windows Phone 7.1**.

Comment: I tried that before I think but tried again but:

`Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Clipboard' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`.

Comment: Show the exact code you are using, as I guess you have something wrong in the way you are trying to use it. Make sure that System.Windows.dll that is referenced is version 2.0.5.0.

Comment: I use code like `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(text);` or `Clipboard.SetText(text);` (having `using System.Windows` in the file anyway) and get the error in the last comment.

Comment: just checked, System.Windows is 2.0.5.0 (v2.0.50727)

Comment: `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;`

and a bit later I have (text is declared in the class and works elsewhere)

`private void copyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(text.Text);
        }` (sorry for the formatting)

Comment: maybe as I use a solution developed before any Mango updates (before VS Mango Beta1) the target OS version is wrong and this might be a problem? If I start a new project VS asks if Win 7.0 or 7.1. But I cannot find any way to change this in a given solution. (Actually this is a wild guess only for my problem).

Comment: Okay, there is your problem. Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and select "Upgrade to Windows Phone 7.1".

Comment: thanks, there are just too many options in VS and I am not used to it (obviously)